# Gravity Compensation with Orocos PyKDL always gives Zero

Tags: ros, robotics, kinematics, revolute-joints

I am trying to calculate the necessary gravity compensation for a KDL chain in Python. However, everything i tried results in a zero vector and I don't know what i missed.

The code I was testing with is the following:

```py
import PyKDL
import math


kdlChain = PyKDL.Chain()

joint1 = PyKDL.Joint(8)
frame1 = PyKDL.Frame(PyKDL.Vector(0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
kdlChain.addSegment(PyKDL.Segment(joint1, frame1))

joint2 = PyKDL.Joint(PyKDL.Joint.RotZ)
frame2 = PyKDL.Frame(PyKDL.Vector(0.0, 2.0, 0.0))
kdlChain.addSegment(PyKDL.Segment(joint2, frame2))

joint3 = PyKDL.Joint(PyKDL.Joint.RotZ)
frame3 = PyKDL.Frame(PyKDL.Rotation.EulerZYX(0.0, 0.0, -math.pi / 2)) * PyKDL.Frame(PyKDL.Vector(0.0, 0.0, 2.0))
kdlChain.addSegment(PyKDL.Segment(joint3, frame3))

joint4 = PyKDL.Joint(PyKDL.Joint.RotZ)
frame4 = PyKDL.Frame(PyKDL.Rotation.EulerZYX(0.0, 0.0, math.pi / 2)) * PyKDL.Frame(PyKDL.Vector(1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
kdlChain.addSegment(PyKDL.Segment(joint4, frame4))

jointAngles = PyKDL.JntArray(3)
jointAngles[0] = 0
jointAngles[1] = 0
jointAngles[2] = 0

grav_vector = PyKDL.Vector(0, 0, -9.81)

dyn_kdl = PyKDL.ChainDynParam(kdlChain, grav_vector)

grav_matrix = PyKDL.JntArray(3)

test = dyn_kdl.JntToGravity(jointAngles, grav_matrix)

gravity_compensation_torques = [grav_matrix[i] for i in range(grav_matrix.rows())]

print(jointAngles, grav_vector, grav_matrix, gravity_compensation_torques, test)
```

The first part where the chain is build comes from [this medium post](https://medium.com/@sarvagya.vaish/forward-kinematics-using-orocos-kdl-da7035f9c8e).
The second part where the necessary torques should be calculated is [from here](https://answers.ros.org/question/286904/get-arm-gravity-compensation-joint-efforts-from-urdf-joint-positions-and-grav-vector/)

I already tried to modulate the chain, change the gravity vector for testing multiple directions and changing the joint angles. Nothing worked, the resulting grav matrix keeps being filled with zeros.

I expect to somehow get a vector that describes the necessary torques for all joints to compensate the exact force described in grav vector. However, i still don't get how I can include the weights of the joint and segments, maybe this is the key for solving this problem.